# Python - Split list of coordinates from one big String

Tags: python, arrays, list, file, coordinates

I have a .txt file containing a list of lists, each list is a set of coordinates:

```
[[151.22999572753906, -33.84008789062494], [..., ...],... [..,..]]
```

I want to know how I can read this file as an array and not as a string so I can easily extract all the coordinates I need.

My code so far:

```
import re

d = '[[151.22999572753906, -33.84008789062494], [151.22999572753906, -33.84008789062494][151.22999572753906, -33.84008789062494]]'
##l = re.split('[\[\]]', d)
l = re.split('\]\[', d)
print(l)

>>>['[[151.22999572753906, -33.84008789062494], [151.22999572753906, -33.84008789062494', '151.22999572753906, -33.84008789062494]]']
```

Comment: Have you tried anything though? What didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the contents of your file happen to be valid JSON. If you're sure the format isn't going to vary, you can just use `json.load`

```
import json
json.loads('[[151.22999572753906, -33.84008789062494]]')
# or
json.load(open('/path/to/your.txt'))

[[151.22999572753906, -33.84008789062494]]
```

Comment: I get the following error :

`JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 27247 (char 27246).` where column 27247 is "]]"

Comment: Sounds like your data isn't entirely described by the format you outlined. 
You may need to write your own parser. What characters immediately precede & follow column 27247?

Answer (score 0):

Start with

> PSEUDOCODE

```
with open(.txt)
    n = 0
    while True
        line = readline
        n += 1
        print(n , line)
```

How many Lines did you read?

Comment: I have only one line actually but it contains multiple lists : 

`[[151.22999572753906, -33.84008789062494], ... [...,...]][[...,...]...[...,...]]` and there is no character between these lists

Comment: @Karim: You show `, ` between, try the code from the Question.